# How to secure database credentials stored in Laravel environment files?

Tags: php, security, laravel

I've recently switched to environment based application deployments for Laravel and I've decided to store credentials for my local and production server in .env files using $_ENV however I've discovered when debugging is turned on and an exception is thrown the error displays the environment variables exposing database credentials.

Now I'm certain debugging will always be off on production because that's what I have it default to, then I override it in a local folder for my local environment however, what **if** somehow someway debugging is turned on on production and a user forces a 404 exception, all they need to do is read down the page until they see the environment variables in plain view exposing credentials. In the docs, it said it's best practice for any 'real' application to keep database credentials away from the actual config. *I may be a bit paranoid here.*

Is there a way I can limit what is shown in the debug screen displayed by laravel?

Comment: It seems to me that you're being a bit paranoid, yes.

Comment: You've got to agree a tiny bit here it's a security concern if debugging is ever left on in production, even for a second by accident. I'm trying to protect myself from ever making that mistake.

Comment: Just as there is a security concern if you happen to make your .env files accessible through the web, even for a second by accident. Or if you simply remove your database's password, even for a second by accident. Or if you just forget a `Auth::check()`, even for a second by accident. Turning debug mode on *by accident* doesn't seem like the sort of thing anyone with more than 2 neurons would do.

Comment: Not really trying to offend here, but this is not the kind of thing that happens by accident and what reason would anyone have to turn debug mode on production, even for a second? Probably the same reasons they would have to completely erase your database, or do anything else completely stupid. This is no rocket science.

Comment: Here's a scenario, before uploading to production, I upload to staging with the debugging on. If I need a few users to come on and test some features, they most likely will trigger an error wether it be 404, 405 etc. Those credentials will be visible to them and I think it's best never to be displayed, ever. Even to myself.

Comment: Farewell, while that is not a reason to have debugging enabled on **production**, I see a point in wanting to hide some information while having debug mode on. I'll post a suggested solution for that use case.

Answer (score 7):

I just recently bumped into the same problem, while a project I was working on required me to temporarily open up my dev machine to the evil outside world to test some API callbacks.

Hereby, I exposed all my precious keys and passwords whenever `whoops` was triggered. Even if it was a blind API callback machine, chances of them logging responses to their requests and some engineer sifting through them and finding some AWS keys, no thanks.

This is what I'm using now:

```php
App::error(function (Exception $exception, $code)
{
    // Never, ever, use environment variables in responses, not even when debugging
    $_SERVER = array_except($_SERVER, array_keys($_ENV));
    $_ENV = [];
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel uses Whoops (`filp/whoops`) to create the debugging page, and you can see [here](https://github.com/filp/whoops/blob/a1d1f5c10e21e14221985a8f95ee7081b68f991c/src/Whoops/Handler/PrettyPageHandler.php#L169)  that it uses `$_ENV` to get the environment variables. While not ideal at all, you *could* simply empty `$_ENV` in case an error is thrown in any environment other than local.

That is pretty straightforward to do by simply rewriting `App::error` (and probably `App::fatal` too) in `app/start/global.php` to something like this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code) {
    Log::error($exception);

    if (App::environment() !== 'local') {
        $_ENV = [];
    }
});
```

This works because the exception handler is called before the Whoops handler.

Now, the *right*, *better* way to do it would be to create a class extending `Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler` which would not display the environment variables or changing any other unwanted behavior and, based on the environment, register it as the `whoops.handler` component for your app, similarly to how it's done on `Illuminate\Exception\ExceptionServiceProvider:registerPrettyWhoopsHandler`. I don't think this is worth all that trouble, though.