# Remove hardcoded Mysql Credentials in Laravel Framework

Tags: php, security, laravel-5, credentials

Sorry if my question is dumb, but i can't find any help on this. I got a Laravel 5 application testing report recommending to remove the hard coded credentials from `app/config/database.php`. But where else do i save the DB credentials and how?

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320725/how-to-secure-database-credentials-stored-in-laravel-environment-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `.env` file in laravel project root. You should add credentials there.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

And in `database.php` -

```
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

For better understanding, read Laravel official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration).

Comment: but what about windows environment?

Comment: same for windows too, laravel project include a `.env` file, it is mainly for configuration of project crdentials

Answer (score 0):

You can store these type of informations in your environment (.env) file.

This file exists in your project root, if it doesn't exist, you can create it manually or make a copy of .env.example file if it exists.

An example data storage:

```
//.env file
DB_NAME="project_db"
```

And to use this variable in any other file of your laravel project:

```
ENV('DB_NAME') //returns "project_db"
```

Simple as that.
Note .env files are depending on the environment project is currently using and might have to change on different environments. Usually .env files are not being stored in repositories and are not deploying to a new environment with whole project.